# Get-Cluster works first time, then fails with "server cannot perform requested operation" error

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

The first time I run the following command, it returns the list like it's supposed to:

```
Get-Cluster -Domain "my domain here"  # <--yes I put in my actual domain
```

Yet when I go to run it again I get this error:

> Get-Cluster : Could not retrieve the list of clusters on the network.
>       The specified server cannot perform the requested operation

I've tried restarting PowerShell, running as administrator (I am an admin on all of the servers, including my own PC) and still get the same issue. If I run it again later (seems to be minimum 1/2 hr but never timed it exactly) it works. I'm on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 1):

Guess I'll answer my own question :P

When running this from a server (not my workstation) it worked every time. The servers do not appear to experience the problem, they sit on networks dedicated to servers, and the NetBIOS services on servers works much better than on the client networks.  On a client network, a Windows 7 system becomes the Browse Master for the subnet and gums up the works due to limitations in the client OS.

Hope this helps someone!